# I want to hide a raw-input

Tags: angularjs

I try to hide a row-input using ng-show but doesn't work. The field works in cascade with form.purchase:
- The field is visible if form.achat = R (Renewal)
- The field is empty and masked if form.buy = N (New)
this is my  html code:

```
     <div class="form-group mode-update col-md-10 no-padding">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label font-normal"> {{ 
    'field.investissement.nouveauRenouvellement' | translate }} </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group mode-update col-md-12 
   no-padding">
                <div class="radio-inline">
                    <label for="achatBudgetTrue">
                        <input  ng- 
   disabled="disabledField" ng-checked="true" type="radio"   ng-true- 
 value="A" ng-false-value="B" name="achatBudget" value="N" ng- 
 model="entity.achatBudget" id="achatBudgetTrue"{{ 
        'field.investissement.achatBudget.nouveau' | translate }}
                    </label>
                </div>
 <div class="radio-inline">
 <label for="achatBudgetFalse">
 <input ng-change="operations.changeEntityField" 
 ng-disabled="disabledField" type="radio" name="achatBudget" value="R"
  ng-model="entity.achatBudget" id="achatBudgetFalse">
                        {{ 
    'field.investissement.achatBudget.renouvellement' | translate }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <raw-input
        property="field"
        vertical="true"
        ng-repeat="field in fields | updateParams:metadata | 
  filter : { fieldSet : 'fieldset.investissement.descriptif'} | filter : { 
   name : 'parcAncienBudget' }"
        entity="entity"
        on-update="operations.updateEntityField"
        on-change="operations.changeEntityField"
        metadata="metadata"
        ng-show="entity.achatBudget =='R'"
        mode="update"
        ng-show = "false"
        creating="creating"
        style="{inputSize: 'col-md-10 no-padding'}">
    </raw-input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two times an `ng-show`-attribute in your attributes:

```
<raw-input
  ...
  ng-show="entity.achatBudget =='R'"
  ...
  ng-show = "false"
```

The value of the second overrides the value of the first, so the element is never shown, no matter what value `entity.achatBudget` has.

Answer (score 0):

I add a function in js:

```
 $scope.isBudgetAchatVisible = false;
    $scope.ShowParc= function(value) {
    $scope.isBudgetAchatVisible = (value == "R") ? true : false;
      }
```

and in the view:

```
  <div class="radio-inline">
 <input  ng-checked="true" ng-change="ShowParc('N')" ............... > 
 </div>
<input ng-change="ShowParc('R')".....................>
 </div>
 <raw-input
  ng-if="isBudgetAchatVisible
  ..............
 </raw-input>
```